React-navigation Cannot read propety 'reduce' of undefined NativeStackView
I'm trying to use @react-navigation/native and I get this error.
Render Error
Cannot read propety 'reduce' of undefined
Source
const preloadedDescriptors = state.preloadedRoutes.reduce((acc,route) => {

Call stack
NativeStackView
NativeStackView.native.js
...
More over, this may not be related but I wanted to include it in case it is.
When I look inside my IDE at the loginScreen line, TypeScript says:
TS2339: Property navigation does not exist on type
Omit<NavigationHelpersCommon<RootStackParamList, StackNavigationState<RootStackParamList>>, "getParent"> & { ...; } & EventConsumer<...> & PrivateValueStore<...> & StackActionHelpers<...>

I followed the documentation on here... But it doesn't seem to work for me.
Here is my code:
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as React from 'react'
import {Text} from "react-native";

type RootStackParamList = {
  Login: undefined
}

type LoginScreenProps = NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Login'>;


export default function App() {
  const LoginStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  const LoginScreen = ({navigation}: LoginScreenProps) => (
      <Text>Test</Text>
  )

  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <LoginStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
      <LoginStack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
      />
    </LoginStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}



did you figure this out?

Most probably you are mixing versions 6.x and 7.x of @react-navigation/xxx components.
In my case this was the line where it happened:
@react-navigation/native-stack/src/views/NativeStackView.tsx 
Line:47 state.preloadedRoutes.reduce 

The preloadedRoutes is undefined in @react-navigation/routes StackNavigationState v6, and appears only in v7, hence the error message.
I found that I had my project dependencies in package.json were conflicting:
@react-navigation/native: ^6.0.0
@react-navigation/native-stack: ^7.0.8

both depend on
@react-navigation/core (in my case different versions obviously) 
which depends on 
@react-navigation/routes (where the StackNavigationState should contain the missing property "preloadedRoutes")

My advice is to check the dependencies and versions.
P.S. My apologies for bad formatting.
